# Django - Moving from one category post to the next and back

Tags: django

> There is a model and posts attached to it.
> I can not figure out how to make the transition from the active post to the next and back.
> I read many articles, but I did not find the right one for me.
> Here is my code. How can this be done?

HTML

```
<div class="bootons-navigation">
<span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="#" title="previous">previous</a></span>
<span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="#" title="next">next</a></span>
</div>
```

Models

```
class home(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('URL'))
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   top_description = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=False)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Главная'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Главная'

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class category(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('URL'))
   description = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=False)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.slug

   def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})


class post(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('URL'))
   description = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=False)

   cat = models.ForeignKey('category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    
   def __str__(self):
    return self.slug

   def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug': self.slug})
```

Views

```
def content_category(request, category_slug):
  categorypost=category.objects.filter( slug=category_slug)
  get_list_or_404(categorypost, slug=category_slug)
  return render(request, 'content/season.html',{
  'category':categorypost,
  })



def content_post(request, category_slug, post_slug):
  postpages = post.objects.filter(slug=post_slug, cat__slug=category_slug)
  get_object_or_404(postpages, slug=post_slug, cat__slug=category_slug)
  return render(request, 'content/post.html', {
  'post': postpages,
  })
```

URLS

```
path('', views.ContentHome.as_view(), name='homepage'),
path('\<slug:category_slug\>', views.content_category),
path('\<slug:category_slug\>/\<slug:post_slug\>', views.content_post)`
```

Comment: Can you kindly rephrase your question?I don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: On the page - post two buttons - go to the next and previous post of the same category

Comment: I want to make it possible to navigate to the next post and back on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding a name to your post detail url.

```py
path('', views.ContentHome.as_view(), name='homepage'),
path('\<slug:category_slug\>', views.content_category),
path('\<slug:category_slug\>/\<slug:post_slug\>', views.content_post, name='post-detail')`
```

Expect previous and next post to be passed in context when post page is rendered.
You can build their url from their instance in context

```html
<div class="bootons-navigation">
{% if previous_post %}
<span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url "post-detail" previous_post.category.slug, previous_post.slug %}" title="previous">previous</a></span>
{% endif %}
{% if next_post %}
<span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url "post-detail" next_post.category.slug, next_post.slug %}" title="next">next</a></span>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Fetch a previous and next post to include in context

```py
def content_post(request, category_slug, post_slug):
  postpages = post.objects.filter(slug=post_slug, cat__slug=category_slug)
  current_post = get_object_or_404(postpages, slug=post_slug, cat__slug=category_slug)
  previous_post = post.objects.filter(cat__slug=category_slug, pk__lt=current_post.pk).first()
  next_post = post.objects.filter(cat__slug=category_slug, pk__gt=current_post.pk).first()
  
  return render(request, 'content/post.html', {
      'post': postpages,
      'previous_post': previous_post,
      'next_post': next_post,
  })
```